# NPM, package.json - how to add dependency with "@" in name

Tags: npm, angular, package.json

I am trying to install new Angular 2 RC in my project. Module name in NPM was changed from `angular2` to `@angular/core`. But when I add it to my **package.json**, it tries to install module `angular/core` instead and doesn't find it. When I type

```
npm install @angular/core
```

in console, then Angular 2 is properly installed. Do you know why **package.json** skipps "@" in module name and how to fix it?

//Edit: I found out that it's not just a name, but "@" indicates a `scoped package`. Anyway, this should work using **package.json** (as described in [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope)), but for some reason doesn't.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 with latest updates and my project is an ASP.NET MVC 6 project (which comes equipped with npm support)

Comment: You should use the `package.json` from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `package.json` from [Angular2 Docs](http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html):

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Then make sure and run `npm install` in the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Dov Benyomin Sohacheski, I wasn't aware of this file.
But unfortunately it didn't resolve my problem. The key was my usage of Visual Studio 2015 and possible outdated version of NPM that shipped with it. I installed Node.js and configured Visual Studio to use this version instead of built-in one and it started working.

[Here](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2016/04/bower-with-vs-2015resolve-ecmderr.html) is a tutorial of how to make VS use our own version of GIT instead of built-in one. Steps for NPM are basically the same. One important difference is you cannot just uncheck `$(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External`, because there are also other tools, so you need to add location of NPM above it.

My final configuration:
[image: configuration]

Don't forget to restart VisualStudio after that.